# Web Scraping with Python - Issue getting attribute value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to Webscraping and I'm struggling to get the values of two attributes from specific element

I want to find the `data-diffusion-decimal` & `data-diffusion-history`

[image]

```
soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"RC-runnerPriceWrapper"})
```

What I get back is:

```
<div class="RC-runnerPriceWrapper PC-bestOddsContainer js-diffusionHorsesList js-horsesList js-bestOddsPriceContainer" data-diffusion-horsename="Dinons">  <a class="ui-btn RC-runnerPrice ui-priceBtn_noPrice js-diffusionPriceValue js-betHandler js-runnerPrice js-runnerPriceBestOdds" data-test-selector="RC-cardPage-runnerPrice" href="#"></a>
```

This is as far as I get but what I need isn't contained in the result. Any advice greatly appreciated

Comment: Most likely those attributes were generated dynamically, so you can get them only with tool that support JavaScript execution

Comment: could you share the url of the page that you are trying to scrape this information from?

Comment: Thanks Andersson so I would need to use something like Selenium? As mentioned in the post I'm very new to Webscraping so any advise on what to use or what to do is really appreciated

Comment: @Monkeydave , Selenium, requests-html, PyQt5... Also you can check XHRs in Network tab (F12) - possibly you can get those values by simulating XHR

Answer (score 2):

Maybe these attributes are set dynamically in javascript. To know that, do not use the console but right click on the page then 'View page source'.

If you cannot find these attributes in the source code, they are set with javascript and you need a tool like [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to execute the dynamic part of the page.

Workaround : using the 'Network' tab of your browser console, you can try to see if an ajax request is executed to get the data in the attributes. Instead of parsing your page, you can call the same request and perhaps get the informations in json format.

Comment: Thanks, I can't see the values in the source code so it does look like Selenium will have to be used. Do you have any advice on this tool or good references for study?

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

Use selenium, and something like this

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.RC-runnerPriceWrapper').get_attribute('data-diffusion-decimal')
```